# Using a has_many association with a single table inheritance model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, sti

I'm trying to create a simple `has_many` association between my `Game` and `DLC` models. The challenge I'm facing is that since there's no `DLC` table because of the single table inheritance, there's no way to insert a `game_id`. So if I were to do the following I'd get this error:

```
game = Game.create
game.dlcs

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: games.game_id
```

Here is how my models are currently setup:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dlcs
end

class DLC < Game
    belongs_to :game
end
```

**Note:** DLC refers to *[downloadable content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downloadable_content)*

Comment: Why is it polymorphic?

Comment: To be honest I'm not exactly sure in this case. I was just trying whatever I saw in a previous answer.

Comment: Have you read the Rails Guide on Associations? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Yes but unfortunately there's nothing in there about STI associations.

Comment: *I'd like to do the exact opposite where the active record model, Game has many Downloads.* I'm not sure what exact opposite means.  Typically, if a Game can ***have many*** Downloads, then a Download might only ***belong to*** one Game.  However, if in your scheme a Download can belong to many Games, then check out the association `has_many_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: You had it right the first time where a game has many downloads and downloads belong to one game

Comment: Well, then that is the typical, simple association.  In your Game model you declare `has_many :downloads` and in your Download model, you declare `belongs_to :game`.  Get rid of the `polymorphic: true`.

Comment: Arghhhh...I missed the STI part.  Scratch everything I said.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Why would it make any sense that Download is a kind of game? I can't really see why you think you should be using STI here. And what you would need to do is create a self joining relationship when both end of the association are on the same table. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

Comment: Changed the model name to `DLC` to hopefully make more since of the association. Basically give a definition in rossettistone's answer and provide a link to the definition in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest alternative would be to just use self-joins and add a `parent_id` column to `games`.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dlcs unless self.name == 'DLC'
end

class DLC < Game
  belongs_to :game, foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

If that's absolutely unthinkable you can create a join table.

```
# game_id: int
# dlc_id: int
class GameExtension
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :dlc
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_extensions
  has_many :dlcs, though: :game_extensions
end

class DLC < Game
  has_many :game_extensions
  belongs_to :game, though: :game_extensions
end
```

Comment: If you copy and paste this like I did, `through` is spelled incorrectly and it won't work. I tried editing the post, but I am unable to due to the 6 or more character change requirement enforced by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** *This answer was based on a misunderstanding of the original question. OP has clarified that `Download` refers to `DLC`, and is in fact a decent case for STI.*

It is not my intention to be contrarian, but I'm not sure I see the case for using single-table inheritance in this case. Single-table inheritance is best used when two models are extremely similar in terms of their database columns, yet appreciably different in the context of the application.

Hypothetical models called `Cow` and `Horse` might share the `farm_animals` table for example. You could even make `Stallion` a subclass of `Horse`. This would let you keep all of these models on one table while giving you the convenience of methods like `Stallion.new`, which is really just an abbreviation for `FarmAnimal.new(type: 'horse', gender: 'male')`.

It's not clear to me that the same benefits are present here for the relationship between `Game` and `Download`. If I've missed something crucial, and am delivering useless information with this answer, my humble apologies! Otherwise, I'd suggest reevaluating the use of STI in this case.

Comment: Are you familiar with the term DLC (downloadable content)? Think of it as an expansion pack for a video game. So for instance a game like  "Bioshock" is a core title but then there's an expansion DLC called "Burial at Sea". The DLC inherits all attributes from a game (title, achievements, box art, etc). I wasn't sure if Rails would properly know how to pluralize `DLC` which is why I named the model `Download`. Does that now make sense?

Comment: Ah, that *does* make sense! Let me think on it and see if I can improve my answer.

Comment: I think maxcal has nailed it in the comments to your question. This is a great case for a self-join, and the docs he linked are just the right ones: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins. I haven't seen a self-join with STI before, but I don't see why it wouldn't work!